# SAS: merging on first match only

Tags: merge, sas, one-to-many

I'm looking to do a one-to-many merge in SAS, where I would like to only keep the first match.

Example data below:

```
data one;
  input id $ fruit $;
datalines;
a apple
b apple
c banana
d coconut
;

data two;
  input id $ color $;
datalines;
a amber
b brown
c cream
c cocoa
c carmel
;

data both; 
  merge one two;
  by id;
run;

proc print data=both;
run;
```

As you can see, this is a one-to-many merge.

Is there a way to make it keep only the first match? i.e. the output would be as below:

```
a apple amber
b apple brown
c banana cream
d coconut .
```

The background here is that the first dataset contains properties, and the second contains leases, and I am looking to find only the first lease on a property. I've only just started learning SAS, so it might be that there is a function better suited to this?

Many thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:-

```
/*Creating Datasets*/
data one;
  input id $ fruit $;
datalines;
a apple
b apple
c banana
d coconut
;

data two;
  input id $ color $;
datalines;
a amber
b brown
c cream
c cocoa
c carmel
;


/*Just insert first.Id=1 in your code, it should do the job*/
data both; 
  merge one two;
  by id;
  if first.id =1;
run;

proc print data=both;
run;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: @Mike if my answer helped you solve your query please upvote. See this link: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers